# issue when loading a data file with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I want to train a classifier with scikit, but for doing this first I need to load the corresponding data. I am using the following data file available in:

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/yeast/

When I open it in word it has the following contents:

```
ADT1_YEAST  0.58  0.61  0.47  0.13  0.50  0.00  0.48  0.22  MIT
ADT2_YEAST  0.43  0.67  0.48  0.27  0.50  0.00  0.53  0.22  MIT
ADT3_YEAST  0.64  0.62  0.49  0.15  0.50  0.00  0.53  0.22  MIT
AAR2_YEAST  0.58  0.44  0.57  0.13  0.50  0.00  0.54  0.22  NUC
```

Each file is separated by a double space and every line with a return carriage.

I want to read it with the following command:

```
f=open("yeast.data")
data = np.loadtxt(f,delimiter=" ")
```

and at the end I want to be able to use the following:

```
X = data[:,:-1]  # select all columns except the last
y = data[:, -1]   # select the last column
```

for using:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
```

but when I try to read it the following error appears:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ADT1_YEAST
```

so how can I read this file in Python to use later the MLPClassifier?

Thanks

Comment: I hadn't seen that my original solution gave a `(n,)` shaped array. Take a look at my update, I think it works.

Comment: The `usecols` parameter will let you load the string and float columns separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip the `f=open(...)`, and you can to use `dtype='O'` to make sure `numpy` reads it as an mix of numericals and strings. Because of some inconsistancies in the data structure in the file you linked, it's best to use `genfromtxt` instead of `loadtxt`:

```
data = np.genfromtxt('yeast.data',dtype='O')

>>> data
array([[b'ADT1_YEAST', b'0.58', b'0.61', ..., b'0.48', b'0.22', b'MIT'],
       [b'ADT2_YEAST', b'0.43', b'0.67', ..., b'0.53', b'0.22', b'MIT'],
       [b'ADT3_YEAST', b'0.64', b'0.62', ..., b'0.53', b'0.22', b'MIT'],
       ..., 
       [b'ZNRP_YEAST', b'0.67', b'0.57', ..., b'0.56', b'0.22', b'ME2'],
       [b'ZUO1_YEAST', b'0.43', b'0.40', ..., b'0.53', b'0.39', b'NUC'],
       [b'G6PD_YEAST', b'0.65', b'0.54', ..., b'0.53', b'0.22', b'CYT']], dtype=object)

>>> data.shape
(1484, 10)
```

You can change the dtypes when you call `genfromtxt` (see [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html#numpy.genfromtxt)), or you can change them manually after like this:

```
data[:,0] = data[:,0].astype(str)
data[:,1:-1]= data[:,1:-1].astype(float)
data[:,-1] = data[:,-1].astype(str)

>>> data
array([['ADT1_YEAST', 0.58, 0.61, ..., 0.48, 0.22, 'MIT'],
       ['ADT2_YEAST', 0.43, 0.67, ..., 0.53, 0.22, 'MIT'],
       ['ADT3_YEAST', 0.64, 0.62, ..., 0.53, 0.22, 'MIT'],
       ..., 
       ['ZNRP_YEAST', 0.67, 0.57, ..., 0.56, 0.22, 'ME2'],
       ['ZUO1_YEAST', 0.43, 0.4, ..., 0.53, 0.39, 'NUC'],
       ['G6PD_YEAST', 0.65, 0.54, ..., 0.53, 0.22, 'CYT']], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Or set `dtype=None` to get a `structured` array - 1d with fields corresponding to the file's columns.